# Android Studio breakpoints not working in doinbackground

Tags: debugging, android-studio

I am trying to debug an Asynctask in my Android app, using Android Studio. My breakpoints are working in onCreate and onStartCommand, but none of the breakpoints are working in doInBackground. I know that the code is executing because I am writing lines to the debug log.

Any idea how I can get the breakpoints working in doInBackground?

```
public class BrowseShares extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
            Log.d("SMBBrowseService", "doInBackground Started");
            try {
                String testUser = userId + ":" + passWord;
                NtlmPasswordAuthentication testAuth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(testUser);
```

Comment: @lan M have you done this?

Comment: I found that the breakpoints would only work if I put a log.d statement at the start of the code, but have no idea why

Comment: Yay! 10x Ian! That's a major bug and I can't find it in the issue tracker! Why not post it as an answer? More than 3 years and still not fixed!

Comment: And this bug still exists as I've found out now.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the breakpoints would only work if I put a log.d statement at the start of the code, but have no idea why