# Android Studio breakpoints off of main thread not working

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug my application. I know for a fact that code in a given class A is executing because I have log statements in methods in that class printing when I run the app, however the problem is that when I set breakpoints on that code which I know is executing off of the main thread in class A, and debug the app, the breakpoints don't pause execution.

Breakpoints I have set in onResume() of an Activity class B are executing, so there's something wrong with how Android Studio is choosing to execute breakpoints.

My issue seems similar to this: [Android Studio breakpoints not working in doinbackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943259/android-studio-breakpoints-not-working-in-doinbackground)

I've tried that user's workaround but with no luck.

Comment: Please post your code where you want to set a breakpoint. Try putting a log statement before the place you want to set a breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my .gradle, and .AndroidStudioPreview folders, then restarted my computer and restarted Android Studio. My breakpoints are working properly now. So it was an issue with Android Studio, and the nuclear option worked.

Comment: Too late but if it happens again - you have checked the breakpoint properties, haven't you? Like - there is some checkbox saying "Suspend all threads" or so.